# SwiftUI + Combine: how to assign data to a model with animation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am using `Combine` to fetch matches as the user types in the search field. It works great in terms of debouncing, deduplicating, and fetching the data. But I am unable to animate the entry of the items. When the matches arrive, the `ObservedObject` is updated in an instant and the UI is already showing the matches. I would prefer to animate the entry of the matches instead.

I think the problem is that the matches are set in the `assign` method, which lacks `withAnimation`. Is it possible to somehow add animation in a `Combine` pipeline? Should I use side effects for that instead?

Here is the code:

```
class DictionarySearchViewModel: ObservableObject {        
        @Published var translationMatches = [TranslationMatch]()
        @Published var text: String = ""
        @Published var isLoading = true
        @Published var connectionError = false
        
        private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        
        init() {
            cancellable = $text
                .debounce(for: .seconds(0.1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .removeDuplicates()
                .map { [self] queryText -> AnyPublisher<[TranslationMatch], Never> in
                    
                    if queryText.count < 2 {
                        return Future<[TranslationMatch], Never> { promise in
                            promise(.success([TranslationMatch]()))
                        }
                        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                    } else {
                            
                            return DictionaryService.sharedInstance()
                                .searchMatchesPublisher(queryText)
                                .retry(3)
                                .replaceError(with: [TranslationMatch]())
                                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                        } else {
                            return Future<[TranslationMatch], Never> { promise in
                                promise(.success([TranslationMatch]()))
                            }
                            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .switchToLatest()
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .assign(to: \.translationMatches, on: self)
        }
}


struct DictionarySearchView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: DictionarySearchViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
                ForEach(viewModel.translationMatches, id: \.id) { translationMatch in
                     Text(translationMatch.label)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `.assign(to: \.translationMatches, on: self)` - it creates a strong reference to `self` - use [`assign(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/assign(to:)) instead. But if still doesn't work with animation, then you can use `sink` instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `.animation` and `.transition` on the `Text` that is in the `ForEach`.

```
 Text(translationMatch.label)
   .animation(.default)
   .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .top))
```

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions

Comment: you are basically right, but the animation modifier should be specified after you specify a transition.
in the code you wrote above it will perform you a default animation without the transition.